# {{>loginButtons}} is working everywhere except one Microsoft Surface

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

`{{>loginButtons}}` is working everywhere except a Microsoft Surface. I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on this device. I don't have another to test. What could be causing this? There is no error in the console. The `<div id="login-buttons" class="login-buttons-dropdown-align-"> </div>` is there, but is empty.

The problem is on a production site [www.LanguageTerritory.com](http://www.LanguageTerritory.com). You may or may not see the problem depending on if it is reproducible on another Microsoft Surface or other device or if the problem is now resolved.

What should I be looking for to troubleshoot this?

This is a screenshot of the way it should look when it is displaying correctly:
[image: screenshot of working {{>loginButtons}}]